# Meta-analysis with incomplete data

Tags: r, meta-analysis, systematic-review

I'm doing a meta-analysis comparing infection rates in 2 sub-types of liver operations (say Big surgery Vs Small surgery). I have a few studies which compare the 2 but other studies that only report on infection rates in one sub-type, either Big or small.

I want to do a meta-analysis where I sum the infection numbers in each sub-type and calculate a cumulative OR with overall p-value. When adding these absolute values, is it ok/correct to include those studies that don't compare and only report on one sub-type?

For example:

[image]
Then calcualte OR, CI and p-value on totals...

Comment: You probably want to investigate arm-based network meta-analysis. Putting that into your favourite search engine should give you a variety of options depending on the degree of mathematics you want.

Comment: Otherwise try with multivariate meta-analysis testing various correlations